# Loop json with Vue.js to populate a html table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

On page load I fetch some data in json format from the database. Now I would like to use Vue.js to loop that json and build a html table.

**Javascript/Vue.js part:**

```
callStocks = function () {
          var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
            el: "#stocksTerminal",
            data: {
              stocks: []
            },
            created() {
              axios
                .get("getStocksAvailable/")
                .then(response => {
                  this.stocks = response.data.data;
                  console.log(response.data.data[0].fields.stockName);
                });
            }
          });
};

callStocks();
```

**HTML structure:**

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Company</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="stocksTerminal">
 <tr>
  <td v-for="item in stocks">[[ item.fields.stockName ]]</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Json object:**

[image]

Right now the frontend doesn't render anything. However I don't have any errors from Vue and **the implemented `console.log` shows the correct item `Infineon` in the above example**. I assume that the transmission from Vue to the variable in the fronend doesn't work.

Note: I use `[[...]]` delimiter since my Django framework preserves curly brackets. I have this in another project running successfully and this shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: You iterate as `v-for="stockName in info"`, but you never use `stockName` inside the loop.

Comment: Is the above output for `console.log(response.data);` or `console.log(response);`?

Comment: it is console.log(response.data);

Comment: Are you sure? Can you try `console.log(response.data.info.data) `? Does this five you the array list like `0: Object {fields: Object {}}`

Comment: This is a very simple issue but needs some testing. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: For demo, you can hard-code `this.info` with same data as in `response.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Update: The json on vue devtool show that `info` is not an array you want, you may do this: `this.info = response.data.data` in the `.then` to get the correct data.

Then try this

```
<td v-for="stockName in info">[[ stockName.fields.stockName ]]</td>
```

Use `stockName` in template

Comment: doesn't render still :/

Comment: :adjusted it, the json looks better now, but it still doesn't render anything

Comment: Please make a demo on codesandbox.io as @palash's comment for further testing

Comment: tried to figure out how to use this sandbox, but seems to be the even bigger challenge lol. When `console.log(response.data.data[0].fields.stockName)` it returns `Infineon` which is just right.

Comment: It should works normal as example here: https://jsbin.com/takebavefi/edit?html,output